# How can I automate Google Calendar event creation with Bigin CRM and Zapier? Is there an easier way?

Tags: automation, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I'm currently working to automate the creation of events in Google Calendar by using specific customer and field information from Bigin. Here's what I've started with:

I will create a custom button within Bigin CRM with a custom link from Zapier which will start the automation. Using the name fields in Bigin along with supplemental info (i.e. date of creation + 6 months into the future) a Google Form will auto-populate the names and dates of the future events with the ability to change/add information and event creation dates. This information will then be passed onto Google Calendar so that the events can be created.

This is the basic structure that I have thought of. I'm a beginner at coding and automation, so I'm still trying to gain experience and best-practices. Would this automation work? Are there simpler ways of doing this?

Thanks!

So far I have started playing around in Zapier and Bigin. I know that the custom button is doable and that Zapier has the ability to link Google Forms and Google Calendar together with Bigin. This was the basis of my workflow. The reason I'm using Google Forms as an intermediate app is because our employees need to have the ability to check and make changes to the events that will be created.

Comment: `a Google Form will auto-populate the names and dates of the future events with the ability to change/add information and event creation dates.` I note the reason why you are using Google Forms, but is this functionality something that Is this based on an example that you have seen? OTOH, given that this is purely an untested hypothetical concept lacking in any data or specifics of any outcomes, what are your expectations of answers to this question?